# Meteor and ChartJS dynamically create a chart

Tags: javascript, charts, meteor, chart.js

I'm currently working on a project with Meteor. It is used to create, edit, delete and vote for polls. Now I'd like to have a page where you can see the results of the answers shown with "ChartJS".

I got following code: 
Templates:

```
<template name="pollAnalysis">
    <h3>Auswertung {{title}}</h3>

    {{#each questions}}
        {{> questionAnalysis}}
    {{/each}}
</template>

<template name="questionAnalysis">
    <div class="post">
        <div class="post-content">
            <h3>{{question}}</h3>
            {{> analysisChart}}
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<template name="analysisChart">
    <canvas id="{{_id}}" class="mychart" height="400" width="400"></canvas>
</template>
```

Helpers:

```
Template.pollAnalysis.helpers({
    questions: function(){
        return Questions.find({pollId: this._id});
    }
});
```

First I had the problem that the chartjs didn't get display, I fixed it by doing this (just for a single ID, thats where I get stuck)

```
Template.analysisChart.rendered = function(){
  drawChart();
}

function drawChart(){

  var data = [
    {
        value: 10,
        color:"#27AE60",
        highlight: "#2ECC71",
        label: "trifft zu"
    },
    {
        value: 10,
        color: "#16A085",
        highlight: "#1ABC9C",
        label: "trifft eher zu"
    }
]

  var ctx = $("#Cb8CdtDpdKA9y4Hij").get(0).getContext("2d");
  var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);

  new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
}
```

Now I need the drawChart dynamically.

pseudo code:

```
function drawChart(questionId){

  var data = [
    {
        value: Questions_Users.find({questionId: questionId}, answer: "yes").count(),
        color:"#27AE60",
        highlight: "#2ECC71",
        label: "trifft zu"
    },
    {
        value: Questions_Users.find({questionId: questionId}, answer: "no").count(),
        color: "#16A085",
        highlight: "#1ABC9C",
        label: "trifft eher zu"
    }
]

  var ctx = $("#"+questionId).get(0).getContext("2d");
  var myNewChart = new Chart(ctx);

  new Chart(ctx).Pie(data);
}
```

So I have to give over the questionId from the Template.analysisChart.rendered to the drawChart() function. But how can I get the questionId ("{{_id}}" in analysisChart template) of the current element in the Template.analysisChart.rendered function?

Greetings & happy programming
faebuk

Answer (score 2):

A quick answer would be to use something like

```
Template.analysisChart.rendered = function(){
  Tracker.autorun(function(){
   var data = Questions_Users.find();
   drawChart();
  })
}
```

Or look into observeChanges, something like:

```
Template.analysisChart.rendered = function(){
  Questions_Users.find().observeChanges({
   added:function(id, fields){
    //update Chart.datasets
    Chart.update()
   }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have an example project that just implements the update logic with Tracker and an ReactiveArray (tracker is part of Meteor's front-end, ReactiveArray is similar to Minimongo with fetch): https://github.com/Slava/jsconf-asia-demo/blob/master/tracker.html#L47-L61

To adapt it to a Meteor app, you would start an autorun in template's `rendered` callback and depend on the minimongo query that you fetch and feed to Chart.js. Once you done, tell Chart.js to update itself.